# Javascript Feeding nested array into table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to feed a nested array of integers into a data table (Table is 5 rows X 6 columns). I know I have to use the `firstChild` property but what I have is not working.

```
function fillTable()
{
var mytable = document.getElementById("myTable");
   for(var i=1) i<6; i++){
       for(j=1; j<7; j++){
           mytable.rows[i].cells[j].firstChild.data = myArray[i-1][j-1];
       }
   }

}
```

Note that the nested array is [0-4][0-5]

Comment: Did you check the console? It would point out that you have a parenthesis where there should be a semicolon in `for(var i=1) i<6; i++){`. If that still doesn’t work, please describe in what way it doesn’t work, and how you’re checking. `j` is undeclared, by the way, and strict mode is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that missing semicolon and j is now declared but it still does not work. I'm having this update to a table on an html page but the table cells are all still holding their original values. Is the line with `firstChild` coded correctly?

Comment: Were you meaning to update the text in the cells? Set `mytable.rows[i].cells[j].textContent`.

Comment: Solved it. After fixing the typos you corrected in your first comment, it appears that I just had to ammend the last line to be myArray[i][j]. Careless mistakes is what I get for coding while sleep deprived. Thanks, minitech :)